# Error of 'this' when trying to setState in Modal

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog

I'm trying to do a delete confirmation modal.

```
  handleDelete (){
console.log('handleDelete')
const { something} = this.state
confirm({
  title: 'Are you sure you want delete?',
  content: 'Press Ok to continue, Cancel to return',
  onOk () {
    console.log('onOK')
    this.setState({ something: [] })
  }
})
```

}

After I press the delete button, the confirmation modal will show. If user press ok, then it will delete something behind the confirmation modal.

But the delete can't be done. I have the error message:

```
TypeError: this is undefined
```

on this line:

```
this.setState({ something: [] })
```

Is it that I trying to setstate on an unmounted component?
Then what is the correct way?

Comment: try var _this = this before confirm code, and use _this instead of this

Comment: I have updated my question Jaromanda X. The error reffers to  this.setState({ something: [] }) line.

Comment: yes, that's the line I suspected

Comment: You should use an arrow function to preserve `this`.

Comment: in javascript speak, @SLaks, that's an arrow function, looking up "lambda" in javascript documentation won't lead you to arrow functions - it would require changing the line `onOk () {` to `onOk: () => {`

Answer (score 1):

you can use Arrow function, it worked.

`onOk: () => {
    console.log('onOK')
    this.setState({ something: [] })
  }`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the code for your component but if you are using a `class` component then any method that declared inside a `class` should hard `bind` the `this` object to the `class` instance so you could get access to the `state` object that "lives" inside this instance.

This is usually done in the `constructor` of the `class`:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
}
```

Another approach is to use the [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which will use the lexical context for the `this` key word, that means, if your handler is declared inside a `class` then the lexical context of this method is the `class` itself, hence the `this` key word will reference to the `class`.

```
handleDelete = () => {
  // your code...
}
```

Comment: the `onOk () {` is where the problem lies

Answer (score 0):

```
class Something extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
}

handleDelete() {
    console.log('handleDelete');
    const { something } = this.state;

    confirm({
        title: 'Are you sure you want delete?',
        content: 'Press Ok to continue, Cancel to return',
        onOk: () => {
            console.log('onOK')
            this.setState({ something: [] })
        },
        onOkWithoutArrow: function(){
           this.setState({..});
        }.bind(this);
    });
}

render() {
    return <Component onClick={this.handleDelete} />;
}
}
```